# How to add a class to target section on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and I am having a bit of a problem.
What I am trying to achieve:

I seperated my Page into sections. Each section except for the home-section is outside the screen.
If someone clicks on the about-button for example, the section #about should flow into view, which is the "current" div at this moment.
If you click on an other link, skills for example, the current div (in this example it is the #about-section)shall animate left, and the now new current section - #skills - shall flow into view.

The menu is taken from an existing page and is functioning, that means the clicked link is getting the current-class.

My jquery code:

```
$('.menu-btn1').click(function() {

    $("#about").addClass("active");
    $("#about").animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, "1500");
    $("#myskills").animate({
        left: '-1170px'
    }, "1500");
    $("#myskills").removeClass("active");
});

$('.menu-btn2').click(function() {

    $("#myskills").addClass("active");
    $("#myskills").animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, "1500");
    $("#about").animate({
        left: '-1170px'
    }, "1500");
    $("#about").removeClass("active");
});
```

The menu markup:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="current"><a class=" menu-btn" href="#slider" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">TOP</a></li>
        <li><a class=" menu-btn1 menu-btn" href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a class=" menu-btn2 menu-btn" href="#myskills" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">SKILLS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The markup for the sections:

```
<section id="about" class="sectionID1 sectionID">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Header Starts -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 section-heading">
                    <div class="heading animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="200">ABOUT ME</div>
                    <h1 class="icon-line animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="700"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></h1>
                    <div class="description animated" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="1200">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Header Ends --> 
            <!-- Row 1 Starts -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Left Column Starts -->
                <div class="col-md-3 personal-info col-left animated" data-animation="fadeInRight" data-animation-delay="1700">
                    <div class="line1">FULL NAME<br>
                        <span class="line2">JOHN DOE</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="line1">BIRTHDAY<br>
                        <span class="line2">7 FEB, 1980</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="line1">BIRTH PLACE<br>
                        <span class="line2">MELBOURNE, AUSTRALIA</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="line1">HOBBIES<br>
                        <span class="line2">ART, READING, MOVIES</span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Left Column Ends -->
                <!-- Middle Column Starts -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="2000">
                        <div class="pic owl-carousel" id="my-pic-carousel">
                            <div><img src="img/about/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
                            <div><img src="img/about/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
                            <div><img src="img/about/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Middle Column Ends -->
                <!-- Right Column Starts -->
                <div class="col-md-3 personal-info col-right animated" data-animation="fadeInLeft" data-animation-delay="1700">
                    <div class="line1">ADDRESS<br>
                        <span class="line2">MELBOURNE, AUSTRALIA</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="line1">PHONE<br>
                        <span class="line2">+123-456-7890</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="line1">EMAIL<br>
                        <span class="line2">JOHN@JOHNDOE.COM</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="line1">WEB<br>
                        <span class="line2">WWW.JOHNDOE.COM</span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Right Column Ends -->
            </div>
            <!-- Row 1 Ends --> 
            <!-- Row 2 Starts -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="2200">
                    <div class="intro">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <!-- Row 2 Ends --> 
                <!-- Button Starts -->
                <div class="link-btn"><a href="#myskills"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> MY SKILLS</a></div>
                <!-- Button Ends --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the markup for the skills section:

```
 <div class="container">
            <!-- Header Starts -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 section-heading">
                    <div class="heading animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="200">MY SKILLS</div>
                    <h1 class="icon-line animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="700"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></h1>
                    <div class="description animated" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="1200">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Header Ends -->
            <div class="owl-carousel animated" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="1700" id="myskills-carousel">
                <div class="items">
                    <div id="donutchart1" data-percent="80"> </div>
                    <br>
                    Web 
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <div id="donutchart2" data-percent="70"> </div>
                    <br>
                    Illustration 
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <div id="donutchart3" data-percent="60"> </div>
                    <br>
                    Print 
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <div id="donutchart4" data-percent="50"> </div>
                    <br>
                    Photography 
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <div id="donutchart5" data-percent="40"> </div>
                    <br>
                    Media 
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <div id="donutchart6" data-percent="30"> </div>
                    <br>
                    Photography 
                </div>
                <div class="items">
                    <div id="donutchart7" data-percent="20"> </div>
                    <br>
                    Media 
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button Starts -->
            <div class="link-btn animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="2200"><a href="#education"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> EDUCATION</a></div>
            <!-- Button Ends --> 
        </div>
```

I know this is truly awful written code. Please, don't shout at me.

I have searched for a solution, so I don't have to write a code for every button. Can someone help me please??

Thanks in advance...

EDIT:
I put in the markup for the sections. But they are pretty long, sorry. I am just trying to achieve my goal on an existing page.

And yes, there will be more than two menu-buttons. Something about 6-8 I think.

I thought, that the markup inside the section is not important, because I am adressing only the section.

At the moment, I am trying out event.target! Well, I am sort of trying everything I can find in the internet and what seems to point into my direction.

Comment: could you share the full html ( with the about and myskills divs ) ? and also the css for them ?

Comment: are you just going to have 2 menu buttons or will be there more as well?

Comment: posted an answer below. hope it does the trick

Comment: updated my comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

see here . made a small example. you should be able to adapt it easily to your html structure.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/3c52mbqv/)**

**css code :**

```
#about { 
    position:absolute;
    left:-1170px;
    width:200px;
}
#myskills {
    position:absolute;
    left:-1170px;
    width:200px;
}
#content {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
}
```

**JQ code**

```
$(".menu-btn").click(function(){
var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#content div").animate({left: '-1170px'}, "1500");
    $("#content div").removeClass("active");
    $(target).addClass("active");
    $(target).animate({left: '0px'}, "1500");


});
```

**EDIT**

**from left and from right**

**see here [JSFIDDLE left or right](https://jsfiddle.net/zLgfn3dz/3/)**

css code :

```
.sectionID:nth-child(odd) {
  transform:translateX(-1000px);
}
.sectionID:nth-child(even) {
  transform:translateX(1000px);
}
#section-wrapper { 
  position:relative;

}

.sectionID { 
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  transition:1.5s;
}
.sectionID.active{
  transform:translateX(0px)
}
 body {
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

**JQ**

```
$(".menu-btn").click(function(event){
var target = $(this).attr('href');
event.preventDefault();

    $(".sectionID").removeClass("active");
    $(target).addClass("active");


    });
```

Please let me know if it helps

Comment: Your #content is the wrap around all divs.

I am trying to say, that your content is a seperate div, which is alway in the background. all other divs just float above it.

But yes, generaly that's what I am trying to do..

Is there a possibility to let the divs float in from left AND right? Like the first one from left, the next one from right and so on?

Comment: yes. as you can see in the html. i made a wrapper around the 2 divs. so i can put a position relative for the position absolute of the divs

Comment: do the divs that you want to float left or right and to animate, have a common class ? like the buttons have `menu-btn` ? for ex ` .animateddiv`

it would make things much easier

Comment: They all have the class .sectionID

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but couldn't get it to work. I'll see about that tomorrow. But I think I gonna stick with your first suggestion. That works fine, only a bit laggy. But I think that is because of the Home Screen, which animates every time, I click on a menu button. Let's see, if i can fix that.

But thank you so much till here. You helped me so much....

Comment: well the second solution should work. but it works only if you have only sections with same class in the `section-wrapper ` . otherwise the `nth-child` won't work. 

gald i helped you out  :) if you are satisfied with the answer...don't be shy and rate it ;)

Comment: well i made a mistake in the last jsfiddle . forgot to delete `overflow:hidden` from `section-wrapper ` . edited it now. is should work like a charm. let me know :)

Comment: well i am glad it works :) don't forget to rate my answer as the correct one :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {

        // Get href/id
        var target = $(this.hash);

        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');

        // Check is target exist
        if (target.length) {
             // Hide current section
             $('section.active').animate({
                 left: '-1170px'
             }, '1500');
             $('section.active').removeClass('active');

             // Show target section
             $(target).animate({
                 left: '0px'
             }, '1500');
             $(target).addClass('active');

             return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! this works, but it is a bit laggy, the active section comes into view 1/3 and stops for a moment, then it continues to full view...Do you know why?